Termux reports "No such file or directory" for bash even after using termux-fix-shebang
I'm trying to run a very straightforward "Hello world" batch script in Termux, but it reports the error line 1: #!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory
Here's the script, saved as test.sh:
#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Hello World"

The shebang line (above) has already been fixed using termux-fix-shebang (the file modified timestamp was updated when it ran).
Termux-exec is also installed and up to date (although still didn't seem to work with the standard #!/bin/bash shebangs)
When I try to run the script by typing bash test.sh at the command line, it says:
test.sh: line 1: #!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory
Hello World

I guess I should be relieved that the "Hello World" does get displayed, but what is causing the error on line 1? And how do I get rid of it?
(I have already worked through a number of suggestions from other similar questions and answers here on Stack Overflow - apologies if I've missed something!)
Edit: Adding outputs as requested in comments (here, so the formatting is readable)
~/.../journal/nginx_config $ od -t x1 <test.sh
0000000 ef bb bf 23 21 2f 64 61 74 61 2f 64 61 74 61 2f
0000020 63 6f 6d 2e 74 65 72 6d 75 78 2f 66 69 6c 65 73
0000040 2f 75 73 72 2f 62 69 6e 2f 65 6e 76 20 62 61 73
0000060 68 0a 65 63 68 6f 20 22 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f
0000100 72 6c 64 22
0000104
~/.../journal/nginx_config $ type env
env is /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/env
~/.../journal/nginx_config $


Can't reproduce here with a fresh install. Uninstall termux and install again

It does it on two separate installs of Termux on two different versions of Android, installed today.

Interesting. Would you mind showing us the output of this command od -t x1 <test.sh?

what is output of type env ?

note that termux-fix-shebang is just a simple shell script that calls sed. It always updates the file, even if it makes no changes.

I've added the outputs for od -t x1 <test.sh and type env to the question, as I tried to put them here and the block code formatting didn't work correctly.

Your script contains a UTF-8 BOM, it won't work like that. Run tail -c +4 <test.sh >test2.sh and try bash test2.sh. Or use a proper editor

The command suggested results in another batch script that causes the same error, with what appears to be an incomplete character at the start:
test2.sh: line 1: �#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory
But I was able to remove the BOM and the version without it runs fine. Thank you for your help, @oguz-ismail !

Yeah I realized my mistake and edited the comment. Glad to have helped, have a nice day

The test.sh file was saved in UTF-8 with a BOM (Byte Order Mark) at the beginning. When saved in UTF-8 format with no BOM, it works correctly. Thank you to @oguz-ismail for help identifying the issue in comments (above) 
